# Trouble with closure lifetimes

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I am really struggling with closure lifetimes. I'm making a simple hangman game where all connections play one game. I'm attempting to pass a closure to a channel that will update the game and then broadcast JSON, but I am running into lifetime issues.

```
extern crate names;
extern crate ws;

#[macro_use]
extern crate json;

use names::{Generator, Name};
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use ws::{listen, CloseCode, Handler, Message, Result, Sender};

type Job = Box<FnMut(&mut Game) + Send>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Game {
    word: Vec<String>,
    guesses: HashSet<String>,
    misses: u32,
    progress: Vec<String>,
}

impl Game {
    fn increment_miss(&mut self) {
        self.misses += 1;
    }

    fn update_progress(&mut self, guess: &String) {
        for (i, letter) in self.word.iter().enumerate() {
            if letter == guess {
                self.progress[i] = letter.clone();
            }
        }
    }

    fn status(&self) -> &str {
        if self.misses > 10 {
            "lose"
        } else if self.progress == self.word {
            "win"
        } else {
            "active"
        }
    }
}

struct Server {
    out: Sender,
    tx: std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Job>,
}

impl Handler for Server {
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: Message) -> Result<()> {
        let string_msg = msg.to_string();

        self.tx
            .send(Box::new(move |mut game: &mut Game| {
                if game.guesses.insert(string_msg.clone()) {
                    check_letter(&mut game, &string_msg);
                };

                let status = game.status();

                let progress = game.progress.clone();
                let guesses = game.guesses.clone().into_iter().collect::<Vec<String>>();
                println!(
                    "guesses: {:?}, progress: {:?}, misses: {}, status: {}",
                    guesses, progress, game.misses, status
                );

                self.out.broadcast(json::stringify(object!{
                    "status"  => "status",
                    "progress" => "progress",
                    "guesses" => "guesses",
                    "misses" => "misses",
                }));
            }))
            .unwrap();

        Ok(())
    }

    fn on_close(&mut self, code: CloseCode, reason: &str) {
        match code {
            CloseCode::Normal => println!("The client is done with the connection."),
            CloseCode::Away => println!("The client is leaving the site."),
            _ => println!("The client encountered an error: {}", reason),
        }
    }
}

fn check_letter(game: &mut Game, guess: &String) {
    if game.word.contains(guess) {
        game.update_progress(guess);
    } else {
        game.increment_miss();
    }
}

fn generate_word() -> Vec<String> {
    let mut generator = Generator::with_naming(Name::Plain);
    generator
        .next()
        .unwrap()
        .split("")
        .map(|c| c.to_string())
        .filter(|s| s != "")
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
}

fn start_game() -> Game {
    let word = generate_word();

    Game {
        progress: vec!["".to_string(); word.len()],
        word: word,
        guesses: HashSet::new(),
        misses: 0,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Job>();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut game = start_game();
        for mut received in rx {
            received(&mut game)
        }
    });

    listen("127.0.0.1:3000", |out| Server {
        out: out,
        tx: mpsc::Sender::clone(&tx),
    }).unwrap();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Compiling hang_man v0.1.0 (file:///Users/smykowski/workspace/rust/hang_man)
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:57:22
   |
57 |           self.tx.send(Box::new(move |mut game: &mut Game| {
   |  ______________________^
58 | |             if game.guesses.insert(string_msg.clone()) {
59 | |                 check_letter(&mut game, &string_msg);
60 | |             };
...  |
75 | |             }));
76 | |         })).unwrap();
   | |__________^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 54:5...
  --> src/main.rs:54:5
   |
54 | /     fn on_message(&mut self, msg: Message) -> Result<()> {
55 | |         let string_msg = msg.to_string();
56 | |
57 | |         self.tx.send(Box::new(move |mut game: &mut Game| {
...  |
78 | |         Ok(())
79 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:57:31: 76:10 string_msg:std::string::String, self:&mut Server]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:57:22
   |
57 |           self.tx.send(Box::new(move |mut game: &mut Game| {
   |  ______________________^
58 | |             if game.guesses.insert(string_msg.clone()) {
59 | |                 check_letter(&mut game, &string_msg);
60 | |             };
...  |
75 | |             }));
76 | |         })).unwrap();
   | |__________^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::boxed::Box<for<'r> std::ops::FnMut(&'r mut Game) + std::marker::Send + 'static>, found std::boxed::Box<for<'r> std::ops::FnMut(&'r mut Game) + std::marker::Send>)
  --> src/main.rs:57:22
   |
57 |           self.tx.send(Box::new(move |mut game: &mut Game| {
   |  ______________________^
58 | |             if game.guesses.insert(string_msg.clone()) {
59 | |                 check_letter(&mut game, &string_msg);
60 | |             };
...  |
75 | |             }));
76 | |         })).unwrap();
   | |__________^
```

Comment: I had some troubles helping with your closure issue (my brain can't comprehend the lifetime issues today ...) ... so I decided to rewrite it slightly to use a struct to execute your jobs instead. [You can see my rewrite in the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3bd41a6a840c8046c78cb01551b2d794&version=stable), although it won't compile there (it does locally).

Comment: RE the closure issue though - they'll default to a `'static` bound and I'm having trouble narrowing that down for you and making it compile. I feel like its possible... I just can't see how at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion here because Rust is not very explicit about some features of lifetimes. In this example,

1. A closure's lifetime is limited by the lifetime of all the params moved into it. In your case, the closure is limited  by `self` because of the line `self.out.broadcast`. Note that `self` is actually a reference in this case coming from the `&self` argument in `fn on_message`. Essentially you create something like

   ```
   Box<FnMut(&mut Game) + Send + 'a>
   ```

   Where `'a` is a lifetime of `&self`.
2. When you create a boxed trait object, the default lifetime is `'static`. That means that

   ```
   type Job = Box<FnMut(&mut Game) + Send> = Box<FnMut(&mut Game) + Send + 'static>
   ```

   To avoid this, you can make self cloneable and move `self.clone()` inside this closure.

Comment: What I'm saying is that's limited by moved params lifetime. OFC it lives as long as it lives, but that doesn't convey any info for the question )

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow have shown that lifetimes are one of the most confusing aspects of Rust. When trying to explain them, using vague and confusable terminology is not likely help the people who need it the most.